# animate rotation button on wp7

Tags: windows-phone-7, animation, rotation

> Hello, I'm trying to create a rotation animation on a button between 2 images one for the and another for the front, just like what's happening in tiles.
>
> Any ideas please?
>
> thanks

Answer (score 0):

Very similar to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14505597/creating-custom-tiles-inside-the-wp7-app/14506913#14506913). Check out [Tile Slider](http://tileslider.codeplex.com/) or [Hub Tiles](http://www.windowsphonegeek.com/articles/Windows-Phone-HubTile-in-depth-Part1-key-concepts-and-API).  Alternatively, you could create your own animations.

Comment: i don't think that tiles are the solution because i need to animate them switch a tap event, athorwise tiles they make their animation progmaticly !

Comment: Well, you need animations...and these projects will get your started.  Look at the "spinTile" storyboard that contains the animation "rotateForward" for instance.  http://tileslider.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/96133#1558735